# In postman, how do I take a response body and use it in a new request within Tests

Tags: javascript, postman

I am new to Postman and completely new to Javascript.

I ran a Post request to create a new contract.

Request Body

```
{
        "progSrvcNm": "009",
        "contractPrtyNm": "PostmanAutomationContract",
        "contractCd": "000",
        "signDt": "2018-01-01",
        "startDt": "2018-01-01",
        "endDt": "2025-01-01",
        "remitTerms": 30
}
```

and received an ok Response with the new contract number as the response body.

```
"02974"
```

I now want to save the response body and use it in a Get request to confirm the data I sent in the Post is what is returned in the get for the new contract.

I attempted to save the variable and use the 'Send Request' snippet in Postman, and when I run I only get a response of another new contract number created.

```
let newContractNb = pm.response.json();

pm.sendRequest("http://smat-meddev02/MedeaSMATMEDSQL01AICollationFNGAPI2.AffiliateApi/api/Get/" + newContractNb, function (err, response) {
    console.log(response.json());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way,

**on 1st GET request**, grab the response body and store the required data to postman environment like `postman.setEnvironmentVariable(key, value)` more specifically by doing

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("newContractNb", jsonData.newContractNb);
```

**on 2nd GET/POST request**, To send the `newContractNb`, you need to set it as part of the `GET/POST` request.

**Take it as Ref.:** http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/

Comment: I guess i'm confused. I did the first part and extracted the response to create the variable. Is the second  part using the variable in a separate GEt request? Is it not possible to run another request from the Tests Section of this Post request?

Comment: now I am getting confused what is your requirement :(

Comment: I'm sorry. I wanted to run the post method to create the new contract and obtain the Number as a response. I then wanted to run a Get  for the new contract number to confirm the data matched what I sent in the previous request body. I was thinking I could do all of this within the Tests section of the Post method via the 'send a request' snippet, but I don't know much so that may not be possible, or the best way.

Comment: The solution Curious_mind worked, except instead of saving the variable to from data, I used it in the URL of a Get method.

Comment: @jwatkins glad it helps you somehow, best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

parsed the data from the json response and saved to a variable as recommended.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("newContractNb", jsonData);
```

Then created a GET method using the variable in the URL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYCvm.png)