# How do I save the response body from one request and use it in another request with some changes in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a GET request to OKTA to retrieve some information that uses some variables etc. It returns a body. I have a second request of type PUT where I manually paste the BODY and make a change to one variable. I am trying to determine if I can remove the manual process of pasting in the response body from the 1st GET request onto the second PUT request.

As an example, I have a URL:

```
GET https://{{myurl}}/api/v1/apps/{{instanceid}}
```

This returns some dyanmic JSON data in the payload like so

```
"blah":{ some more blah
},

"signOn": {
        "defaultRelayState": null,
        "ssoAcsUrlOverride": ""
        "audienceOverride": null,
        "recipientOverride": null
    }
```

what I am hoping to do is:

```
PUT  https://{{myurl}}/api/v1/apps/{{instanceid}}
       {replay entire body from 1st request with the modification of

      "ssoAcsUrlOverride": "{{some var that points to a new url}},
```

}

I have looked at some articles that show:

- Using Tests to send a GET request with a static body and replaying that exact body. In this case, I am looking to modify a parameter not replay as=is
- I tried this thread here ([In postman, how do I take a response body and use it in a new request within Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522666/in-)
  postman-how-do-i-take-a-response-body-and-use-it-in-a-new-request-within-tes) but I get an error stating that `responseBody` is not defined

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's validate the JSON response first. Here is the valid JSON with some dummy data.

```
{
    "blah": "some more blah",
    "signOn": {
        "defaultRelayState": "1",
        "ssoAcsUrlOverride": "www.google.com",
        "audienceOverride": "true",
        "recipientOverride": "yes"
    }
}
```

1) Save first request's response into a environment variable `req_body` as follows,

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

pm.environment.set("req_body",  jsonData);
```

2) In the PUT request, take another environment variable `replace_this_body` in body.

[image]

3) Get the value of E'variable `req_body` we had set in the first request in Pre-request script. Then change the value of it and set current request's body variable.

```
var requestBody = pm.environment.get("req_body");

requestBody.signOn.ssoAcsUrlOverride = "https://www.getpostman.com";

pm.environment.set("replace_this_body", JSON.stringify(requestBody));
```

Finally, you will get updated request data into PUT request!

Comment: Fantastic. I finally had a chance to test it and works great.

Comment: Glad to know that!@jeyyu2003  Please accept this an answer don't forgot to upvote the answer if it helped you. Also read [how this answer would help others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)